# What languages attribute sign/unsignedness to the operation not the data?

Tags: types, programming-languages, unsigned

In most higher-level languages, higher than assembly, integer variables have a quality of being signed or unsigned.  In C, "unsigned short" as a data type.   All languages I can think of, C family or Pascal-derived, newer ones like Go, have such data types.  (Some don't offer unsigned, just signed, but never mind those.)

The underlying truth is that all CPUs I've ever studied have signedness associated with operations, or the choice of branch opcode following an operation.  There are signed right-shift and unsigned right-shift opcodes.   Signed and unsigned integers alike go through the same arithmetic circuits, since the 1s and 0s come out the same.  Carry and Overflow flags get adjusted. The distinction comes when a compiler chooses branch-on-carry  vs branch-on-overflow, or some similar choice, based on the symbol table and variable attributes it's built up.

Just curious, since I like close-to-the-silicon languages - are there any higher-level languages, say at the level of C on up, where the integer values are not typed with any signed/unsigned attribute?

I know about the >>> operator in Java.  That's a small example of what I'm asking for, but wondering if there are languages (probably obscure) that thoroughly use distinct operators rather than distinct data types for the signed/unsigned.

(Somewhat related is the question of whether any languages offer access to the C or O flags of the CPU, so you can DIY.)

Comment: Heard of many languages, but not of such. Still love the question, because I once thought about exactly the same.

Comment: the cpu may associate signedness with operators but that is not the proper abstraction for the programmer. signedness is a quality of the datatypes. the underlying representations are different at least in the sense that their domains are not equivalent. it might seem handy to have a sign-preserving shift available as an operator in a high-level language, it's use is still debatable - the sign-preserving right shift is a division by 2 and that probably better  reflects the algorithmic step in the application domain. if the code is actually dealing with bitsets in the problem domain ...

Comment: ... it should be expressed this way by using/defining the suitable data type which may come with its own set of suitable operators. the compiler may map this data type to the best-suited datatype that the cpu/vm supports natively, taking into account the hi-level operations applied to the data and performance criteria (in the example the mapping is easy and doesn not entail any significant performance penalty).

Answer (score 0):

i think from the viewpoint of a language developer, having unsigned and signed operations is rather rare. the java operator >>>, which has the behavior of an unsigned right shift, seems to be an exception and its usage is not so much related to seeing its operands as signed or unsigned (my hypothesis).
if you implement all the signed/unsigned logic as operations, it quickly gets tricky. consider for example the two C assignment:

```
short var_a = -1;
unsigned int var_b = var_a;
printf("%d", var_b); // -1

unsigned short var_a = -1;
unsigned int var_b = var_a;
printf("%d", var_b); // 65535
```

the first case has to perform a sign extension, since it is an upcast from a signed type and the second one mustn't perform a sign extension, since it is an upcast from an unsigned type. i wouldn't want to think about which assignment operation to use for such assignments.

also consider [Gosling's opinion](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm) about that:

> "Quiz any C developer about unsigned, and pretty soon you discover
>   that almost no C developers actually understand what goes on with
>   unsigned, what unsigned arithmetic is. Things like that made C
>   complex. The language part of Java is, I think, pretty simple. The
>   libraries you have to look up."

i agree with him and think that it is just simpler, to have one signed type. people who need unsigned arithmetic in languages like Java, can easily implement it themselves (and i implemented a C interpreter in Java).